# calculate textbox values with jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have simple order form and i want to calculate total and discount live (without clicking a button). also if customer order less then 500 total quantity price will be 26 and if order 500 or more total quantity item price will be 25, if order 1000 or more total quantity item price will be 20.

**HTML Code**

```
<form name="order" id="order" method="post" action="order_form.php">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="item1" name="item1" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="input" id="item2" name="item2" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="input" id="item3" name="item3" value="" />
    <input type="text" class="input" id="total" name="total" value="" />
</form>
```

so if anyone order 200 of item1 and 300 of item 2 or 3 price should be 25. can anyone tell me how to do this. thanks in advance.

Comment: please post some code that you tried

Answer (score 1):

When your cursor `focus` on `total` textbox , it will calculate `sum of all three textbox value`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#total').focus(function(){
        var item1 = $('#item1').val();
        var item2 = $('#item2').val();
        var item3 = $('#item3').val();

        var total = parseInt(item1) + parseInt(item2) + parseInt(item3);
        alert(total);
        $('#total').val(total); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: @zack check my answer , hope it will help you.